request size did not match content length - GraphQL file Upload
I am using apollo client
react UI
"@apollo/client": "^3.8.1",
"apollo-link": "^1.2.14",
"apollo-upload-client": "^18.0.1"
**NodeJs **
"apollo-server-express": "^2.21.1"
File is not getting uploaded Please help   import createUploadLink from "apollo-upload-client/createUploadLink.mjs"
const httpLink = createUploadLink({
uri: ""

});
const link = from([errorLink, httpLink, new HttpLink({ uri:""})]);



export const UPLOAD_FILE = gql `
mutation ($file: Upload!) {
uploadCsv(file: $file) {  
message
}  
}`

const [uploadFile, {data: uploadedData, loading: uploading, error: uploaderror}] = 
useMutation(UPLOAD_File)

const result = await uploadFile({
fetchPolicy: "network-only",        
   
variables: {
      file
}
});

Request Payload:
operations: {"variables":{"file":null},"query":"mutation ($file: Upload!) {\n      
upload(file: $file) {\n    message\n    __typename\n }\n}"}    map: {"1": 
["variables.file"]}    1: (binary)

Reponse preview:
BadRequestError: request size did not match content length
    at IncomingMessage.onEnd (node_modules\raw-body\index.js:277:12)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:524:35)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (node:domain:489:12)
    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1359:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
    us!!


What version of node is this? If it's bun (not node), that's an open issue.
